# How get into sentence to lexeme with space character?

Tags: regex

For example - sentence, where `|` is the sentence boundary. At the end of the sentence, after character `.` located character **space**  :

```
|This is one. |
```

How split this string how this:

```
[This ]
[is ]
[one. ]
```

What I do (regex):
**Regex1:**

```
(\.\s|\s)
```

Result:

```
0: [This]
1: [is]
2: [one]
```

**Regex2:**

```
(?<=[\s\p{Punct}])
```

**Result:**

```
0: [This ]
1: [is ]
2: [one.]
3: [ ]
```

but it does not separate words properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split with `(?<=\s)(?=\w+)`

**Sample code** (python)

```py
import re
a="This is one. "
print(re.split("(?<=\s)(?=\w+)",a))
```

**Output**

```
['This ', 'is ', 'one. ']
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which regex engine you use. So it's quite impossible to give you exact solution.

The splitting regex you need in pcre looks like

`(?<=\s)\b`

Positive lookbehind checks for whitespace before word boundary but doesn't include it in pattern. So trailing whitespace will not be stripped.

Answer (score -1):

Regex:

```
(?<=[\s])
```

for sentence:

```
"This is one. "
```

return result:

```
0: [This ]
1: [is ]
2: [one. ]
```